# Angular Slickgrid reloading data with column headers

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

On page load, I'm rendering the `angular-slickgrid` which is working fine. later, I want to change the column header names, removing a particular column & enabling editable columns based on some condition. So I'm modifying the values of `columnDefinitions` and `gridOptions` as my wish but its not reloading the entire grid.

how to reload the complete grid with updated columns headers dynamically ?

Comment: The [Example 3](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/editor) has dynamic columns with editors in play, you should take a look at that demo

Comment: Thank you.. Its really helped me..